# How to optimize queries that return large data?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, binary-data

I have about 10 documents on MongoDB. Every document pertains to an image, and contains that image's binary data.

Running a mongoose query like `Image.find()` returns an error,

```
Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
            ^

TypeError: Error.captureStackTrace is not a function
```

Rerunning the query as `Image.find().limit(10);` takes 22 seconds.

The query `Image.find().limit(3);` takes 4 (oddly enough, considering one would expect it to run in no less than ~7, if 10 records take 22 seconds).

Anyway, I'm wondering what I can do here. Other than hosting the images on something like S3, of course.

What could be nice, is I could take this opportunity to implement pagination.. But what user would want to wait 4 seconds per page?

Any thoughts/suggestions? This would also kill the client if I store this large data in the state.

Comment: My suggestion is to use your file system to save the image data and save their path in mongodb. It is a blazing fast method to serve images.

Comment: So something like s3, right? I guess that's the logical thing to do here.

Comment: Using s3 has its own advantages. But it may have some cost associated with it. You can also serve images to the client using static file serving techniques through your own file system.

Comment: What mehta-rohan said.